Count filled in form fields in GA4
I'm trying to count form fields that are filled in before a form is abandoned using a custom HTML GTM tag containing the following:
<script>
document.querySelector('.Form').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'form interaction',
        'form_field': e['target'].getAttribute('name')
    });
});
</script>

GTM preview seems to be ok with it and when focus is removed from an input it's firing the tag.

However, nothing is in GA under events. I've looked at a lot of very long blog posts on the topic today and have got in a bit of a twist with variables, custom triggers and other things, but can't wrap my head around them.
What else needs to happen for those events to show up in GA?

dataLayer (DL) push on it's own doesn't automatically cause GTM to send events. There's another layer of logic that GTM provides so that people who don't know how to code could still have some power over how DL pushes work and even allows people to eval custom JS to mutate the content of the DL.
In GTM, you need to make a tag that... Actually, I outlined it before here: sendGTMEvent for Next.js does not submit to Google Analytics That is essentially the same question as yours, but with some framework details. I have a list of actions to be taken after the DL push is there. Check out the comments there too. Let me know if I can clarify that answer. I'm too deep in technical analytics to see what's obvious and what's not anymore.

Thanks, I'm still a little confused. The 3 steps you outline include a trigger a step 2. Is it used as a trigger for either or both of the tags from steps 1 and 3?

2 is for 3. 1 is triggered on real pageloads only. 1's main aim is to load and configure the library. I mention in 1 how to trigger it.
